# How to copy / move uv loop layers

Tags: rendering, uv

I have an object with two parts each has been uv'd on to a different loop layer with textures.  On rendering the object only one of the texture layers is shown.
How to transfer both uv loops on to one for rendering?  I am using Blender 2.91.
The online manual isn't very helpful about uv loops.

Comment: Do you mean merge two UVMaps?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  As I understand merge command, it joins two vertex and makes one.  My problem is that the torso and face of my model is on UV map 1 and the legs are on UV map 2.  How to combine map1 and map2 on to, say, map3.  Or to put map 2 onto map 1.

Comment: There is only one way to do this. You have to separate the model by the UVMaps (Select one of the regions hit "p" and choose By Selection). Delete the unnecessary UVMap slot on each model. Then rename one of the UVMap to the same as the other. Join the models again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'll do this as soon as I get back to modelling.  Thanks again for your help.  The origin of the problem was my mistake which went unnoticed until a lot of work had been done